# “grep -oe” works, but not “grep -eo”

Tags: shell, grep

At my terminal prompt, `echo 'Banana' | grep -oe 'n'` works as expected:

```
$ echo 'Banana' | grep -oe 'n'
n
n
```

but not `echo 'Banana' | grep -eo 'n'` :

```
$ echo 'Banana' | grep -eo 'n'
grep: n: No such file or directory
```

Why does the order of `-e` & `-o` matter?

Comment: `-eo` means "look for the regular expression `o`. The following `n` is interpreted as a filename. The non-posix flags *can* be confusing when they're bundled. The reason it matters is that the very next thing that follows `-e` is going to be interpreted as the regular expression. To have it behave any other way would be devastating.

Comment: `-e` must be followed immediately by the search pattern, so you need `grep -e 'n' -o` if you want to put `o` after `e`

Comment: Now I see that you're right:`-e` signifies that what follows is the pattern; thus `-e` must come last; this allows for patterns that begin with a `-`.
$ echo 'Banana' | grep -e -o 'n'
grep: n: No such file or directory
$ echo 'Banana' | grep -o -e 'n'
n
n

The man page refers to this. For example,
$ echo 'high-end' | grep -e -e
high-end
Not 100% true, though: the man page says `-e` & `-f` can be combined. Consider:
$ echo 'dog-f ood' | grep -e -f ood
grep: ood: No such file or directory
But:
$ touch a.txt
$ echo 'high-end' | grep -e -e a.txt
$ echo 'high-end' | grep -e -e -f a.txt
high-end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please observe the outputs attached below.
-e is for an expression it is considering o as expression in file n.

[image: example]

Comment: Now I see that you're right:`-e` means that what follows is the pattern; thus `-e` must come last, allowing for patterns that begin with a `-`.
`$ echo 'Sand' | grep -e -o n`
`grep: n: No such file or directory`
`$ echo 'Sand' | grep -o -e n`
`n`
The man page refers to this. For example,
`$ echo 'high-end' | grep -e -e`
`high-end`
Not 100% true, though: the man page says `-e`&`-f` can be combined. Consider:
`$ echo 'dog-f ood' | grep -e -f ood`
`grep: ood: No such file or directory`
But:
`$ touch a.txt`
`$ echo 'high-end' | grep -e -e a.txt`
`$ echo 'high-end' | grep -e -e -f a.txt`
`high-end`